# Polymorphic relationship with other polymorphic realtion?

Tags: laravel

I have `order` and `return` tables which have a `created_by` and `accepted_by` field where the corresponding user id is stored.
But now I would like to have multiple types for created_by and accepted_by instead of only user type. Assume a `company` could also create or accept the order/return.

I was thinking of a polymorphic one to many relationship.
Let’s name this table `participants`.
Something like:

| ID | created | participantable_id | participantable_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | user |
| 2 | 0 | 11 | company |

This works either for order or return but not both.
Is it practically to add extra colums to `participants` like `trx_id` and `trx_type` (order/return)?

How would the realtionships looks like to perform queries like:

```
$order->createdBy // should give me either user or company model
$order->acceptedBy
$return->createdBy
$return->acceptedBy
```

Or is there even a cleaner solution I am overlooking?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be 1:N polymorphic relationships so no need for an extra table. The structure can be found in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

Your `Order` and `Return` model need to have the columns `created_by_id`, `created_by_type`, `accepted_by_id`, `accepted_by_type`.

```
                ______ (1) Company
               /
Order (N) ----<
               \______ (1) User

                 _____ (1) Company
                /
Return (N) ----<
                \_____ (1) User
```

```php
class Order extends Model
{
    public function created_by()
    {
        return $this->morphTo(__FUNCTION__, 'created_by_type', 'created_by_id');
    }

    public function accepted_by()
    {
        return $this->morphTo(__FUNCTION__, 'accepted_by_type', 'accepted_by_id');
    }
}
```

```php
class Return extends Model
{
    public function created_by()
    {
        return $this->morphTo(__FUNCTION__, 'created_by_type', 'created_by_id');
    }

    public function accepted_by()
    {
        return $this->morphTo(__FUNCTION__, 'accepted_by_type', 'accepted_by_id');
    }
}
```

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function created_orders()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Order::class, 'created_by');
    }

    public function accepted_orders()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Order::class, 'accepted_by');
    }

    public function created_returns()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Return::class, 'created_by');
    }

    public function accepted_returns()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Return::class, 'accepted_by');
    }
}
```

```php
class Company extends Model
{
    public function created_orders()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Order::class, 'created_by');
    }

    public function accepted_orders()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Order::class, 'accepted_by');
    }

    public function created_returns()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Return::class, 'created_by');
    }

    public function accepted_returns()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Return::class, 'accepted_by');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, I am able to query as I wanted. But I am not able to do: `$order->acceptedBy()->save($restaurant)` any idea why this is not working?

Comment: What is `$restaurant`?

Comment: Ah sorry I mean `$company`

Comment: The inverse is working: `$company->acceptedOrders()->save($order)`

Comment: You need to do `$order->acceptedBy()->associate($company)->save();`